# C++ base64decode returns junk data if it contains '\0'

Tags: c++, openssl, binary, base64, decoding

We have an certificate file (binary) having '\0' in multiple places. While trying to decode using openssl it gives junk data while size used to be perfect.

Same code works perfectly if there is no '\0' in the base64encoded data

We tried achieving it using below code but still file is not readable

```
static const std::string base64_chars =
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"0123456789+/";

static inline bool is_base64(unsigned char c) {
    return (isalnum(c) || (c == '+') || (c == '/'));
}
std::string base64_decode(std::string const& encoded_string) {
    int in_len = encoded_string.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int in_ = 0;
    int in_1 = 0;
    unsigned char char_array_4[4], char_array_3[3];

    std::string ret;
    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("output_file.pfx", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    bool f = isalnum(encoded_string[in_]);
    while (in_len-- && (encoded_string[in_] != '=') && is_base64(encoded_string[in_])) {
        char_array_4[i++] = encoded_string[in_]; in_++;
        if (i == 4) {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                char_array_4[i] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[i]);
            }
            char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
            char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
            char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

            for (i = 0; (i < 3); i++)
            {
                if (char_array_3[i] != NULL)
                {
                    ret += char_array_3[i];
                    char val = char_array_3[i];
                    outfile.write(&val, sizeof(char));
                }
                else
                {
                    /*char str3[3155];
                    strcpy(str3, ret.c_str());
                    ret = "";
                    ret.append(str3, sizeof(str3));*/
                    ret += "NUL";
                    char val111 = char_array_3[i];
                    outfile.write(&val111, sizeof(char));
                }
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            char_array_4[j] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[j]);

        char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);

        for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++)
        {
            if (char_array_3[i] != NULL)
            {
                ret += char_array_3[i];
                char val1 = char_array_3[i];
                outfile.write(&val1, sizeof(char));
            }
            else
            {
                ret += "NUL";
                char val11 = char_array_3[i];
                outfile.write(&val11, sizeof(char));
            }
        }//ret += char_array_3[j];
    }
    outfile.close();
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    base64_decode("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");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make this into a [MCVE]? Include some _small_ sample data and tell us what the output should be instead of what it is.

Comment: I must be missing something but base64 data should not contain `'\0'`. Maybe you're mixing up decoding and encoding?

Comment: BTW `outfile.write(&val1, sizeof(char));` would be better as `outfile.put(val1)`

Comment: John's right; the valid characters are listed in your `base64_chars` and `'\0'` is quite rightly not one of them.

Comment: '\0' is part of binary file that is encoded to base64encoded string. It is actually a byte having NUL. If the base64encoded data contains actual byte as '\0' then it creates problem in decoding.

Comment: Added sample base64encoded data for verification.

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem here. Your sample code does not contain any `\0`s.

Comment: other than the last 2 bytes your code produces the same result as an online base64 decoder for the provided base64 string

Comment: The last 2 bytes are corrected by changing the `char_array_3` indexes in the final loop from `i` to `j`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the handling of the trailing bytes, you are using `i` as the array index instead of `j`. As `i` can be larger than the size of `char_array_3` it produces undefined behaviour. The correct code is:

```
    for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++)
    {
        if (char_array_3[j] != NULL)
        {
            ret += char_array_3[j];
            char val1 = char_array_3[j];
            outfile.write(&val1, sizeof(char));
        }
        else
        {
            ret += "NUL";
            char val11 = char_array_3[j];
            outfile.write(&val11, sizeof(char));
        }
    }
```